# Getting 'repository not found' when using multiple ssh keys / github accounts

Tags: git, github

I've been using the following setup for a while to switch between multiple ssh keys and github accounts.

Firstly I have two keys in .ssh/

```
id_rsa_work
id_rsa_work.pub
id_rsa_personal
id_rsa_personal.pub
```

And a config for those keys

```
Host personal
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

Host work
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

And then I'm able to switch between accounts by doing

`ssh -T work` or `ssh -T personal`

and then I use two gitconfig files to auto pickup the git config.

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    name = hex6b
    email = kaigo@personal.com

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

**~/work/.gitconfig**

```
[user]
        name = My work name
        email = my.name@work.com
```

The work setup seems to work fine, however the **personal one will not allow me to** clone new repos or push/pull existing repos.

> ERROR: Repository not found.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Not sure why it's suddenly not working, maybe since github introduced [personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

I can also see both keys when I do a `ssh-add -l`
so I don't need to add them to the ssh agent.

Do I need to do anything special with the urls from github? Usually I just copy them from the code dialog.

[image]

Comment: seems I need to change url to git@personal:hex6b/reponame.git but only for personal, work seems to be okay and I can use default from github.com

Comment: Make sure you're using the right URLs, yes. Consider also using the `insteadOf` feature in those Git config fragments: you can auto-replace `ssh://git@github.com/` with the right personal-vs-work URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to change the URLs.  The [Git FAQ explains how to do this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-ssh) by changing the URL in each case.

The example configuration they give looks like this:

```
# This is the account for author on git.example.org.
Host example_author
    HostName git.example.org
    User git
    # This is the key pair registered for author with git.example.org.
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_author
    IdentitiesOnly yes
# This is the account for committer on git.example.org.
Host example_committer
    HostName git.example.org
    User git
    # This is the key pair registered for committer with git.example.org.
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_committer
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

In this case, the hostname would be `example_author` or `example_committer` instead of `git.example.org`.